# Navigation Drawer seems to be over the tablayout

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-tablayout

I'm a creating a app with navigation Drawer and TabLayout. I created the navigation Drawer and added the TabLayout, each tab is supossed to have a fragmente, but the fragment isn't appearing, it's like the Draweaver is "covering" them. Does someone knows what's my mistake here?

Home activitiy

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity


        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseUser currentUser ;


    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private PagerAdapter adapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //TabLayout
        tabLayout =(TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout_id);
        viewPager =(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_id);
        adapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        //Add fragment
        ((PageAdapter) adapter).AddFragment(new AnuncioFragmento(),"Anuncio");
        ((PageAdapter) adapter).AddFragment(new PedidoFragmento(),"Pedido");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);



        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();


        //MenuView
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        updateNavHeader();

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The fragments are added on this XML that are the app_bar_home

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Atividades.Home">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:id="@+id/tablayout_id"></android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/viewpager_id"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>



    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="290dp"
        >

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_add_blue"
            app:fab_size="mini"
            android:id="@+id/add_anuncio"
            app:fab_title="Anúncio" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_add_blue"
            app:fab_size="mini"
            android:id="@+id/add_pedido"
            app:fab_title="Pedido" />



    </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>

    <include layout="@layout/content_home" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I said it's covering the fragments and the tab, because the tabs don't slide and i changed the coolor of the fragments and it isnt showing on the app. After that i changed the Collor of the Drawlayout XML and it's showing.

Please what did i do wrong?

Edit PageAdapter

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> listfragment = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> listTitle = new ArrayList<>();



    public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return listfragment.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listTitle.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return listTitle.get(position);
    }


    public void AddFragment (Fragment fragment, String title ) {

        listfragment.add(fragment);
        listTitle.add(title);

    }
```

Fragmento 1

```
public class AnuncioFragmento extends Fragment {
    View v;



    public AnuncioFragmento() {
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.anuncio_fragment, container, false);


        return v;
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/anuncio_reciclerview">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragmento 2

```
public class PedidoFragmento extends Fragment {

    View v;




    public PedidoFragmento() {
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pedido_fragmento, container, false);




        return v;
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/pedido_recyclerview"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're returning the correct number of fragments in `getItemCount()` in your `PageAdapter` class. As I see in your code, you must have a value 2 returning.
Anyway, show us that `PageAdapter` class.

Comment: I just added the page adapter on the post

Comment: You said "After that i changed the Collor of the Drawlayout XML and it's showing.", where did you change that color, what do you mean?

Comment: I was trying to figure out why my datas aren't showing on my app, to do that i tried to first check if my fragments was connected correcly so i just changed the background Collor of a fragments and it did not changed on the app. So after i did that, i changed the background Collor of the secound XML of the post, and it changed on that app too, on both "fragments". So i realized the Navigation Drawer is over the Tablayout. I'm new on programing, i don't if what i saying make sense.

Comment: Share your fragments classes and xml.

Comment: I just added now

Comment: Try the new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this.

Change your adapter class to:

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // Or use fragmentList.add(...), titlesList.add(...) here.
        // The fact is that you have to init all fragments and titles in this class.
        // After that, you may create a new PageAdapter object and set to ViewPager.
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return new FragmentOne();
        } else {
            return new FragmentSecond();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return "Title 1";
        } else {
            return "Title 2";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's showing "method call expected" when i write "return AnuncioFragment ();" what should i wirte there?

Comment: Ups, I missed "new" keyword, check now.

Comment: still nothing =/

Comment: Wait, what is this? <include layout="@layout/content_home" /> Maybe content_home.xml is hidding content in ViewPager, blocking swiping. Show us content_home.xml to check. I'm refering to the second XML on the post.

Comment: Yea, it's make sense. I just removed the navigation Drawer and noew it's working. I'll add it again later and let you know what was the mistake. Anyway, thank you so for your time and your help.